# how can we schedule a task to update patching in windows servers through ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

we have close to 6 thousand windows servers every month to update them to patching and certain products .we are looking for a solution to automate there updation through ansible without using ansible tower/awx. Please can anyone suggest how this can be achieved.

can we combine win_update and win_scheduled_tasks together ?

Comment: Thankyou we will surely look more on Rundeck if it suits our requirements. I still have a doubt regarding win_schduled_tasks and win_update combined to schedule the patching. What are the possible challenges if we go through this approach?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Rundeck](https://www.rundeck.com/open-source) as a replacement for AWX. Rundeck has fine grained scheduling options.